# how to determine the size of a packet

Tags: networking

Suppose I initiate a TCP connection for HTTP request and response. After the completion of three way handshaking process, I now send a request to the server for a HTTP packet with SYN flag set. The server responses to my request with ACK flag. Upon completion of the response, it will send me a FIN flag. Now how can I determine the size of the packet that the server send me during the request and response? Is there any process to do so?

Comment: What language? What platform? Yes there are processes on how to determine packet size but each language and, depending on the language, each platform have a slightly different way to determine packet length/size.

Comment: @bwtrent None of that is true. He is asking about the length of an HTTP response. There is nothing language- or platform-dependent about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose I initiate a TCP connection for HTTP request and response. After the completion of three way handshaking process, I now send a request to the server for a HTTP packet with SYN flag set.

No you don't. The SYN was in the first packet sent in the three-way handshake. That's done. At best you will be piggy-backing the HTTP request on the final ACK packet of the connect handshake.

> The server responses to my request with ACK flag.

No, the server responds to your HTTP request with an HTTP response. The ACK is irrelevant at the HTTP level.

> Upon completion of the response, it will send me a FIN flag.

No it won't, unless you're speaking HTTP 1.0 or you have set the Connection: close header. Otherwise it will keep the connection open for HTTP keepalive.

> Now how can I determine the size of the packet that the server send me during the request and response? Is there any process to do so?

The server didn't send you anything during the request. The size of the response body is given by the Content-length header or the sum of the chunked-encoding section sizes if that's used. You need to read the HTTP 1.1 RFC about this, it's non-trivial.

You also need to stop confusing HTTP with TCP. HTTP is an application protocol layered on top.